# Error 1004 on making pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I keep receiving the error 1004 saying like the below

"**The pivot table field name is not valid. To create a pivot table report, you must use data that is organized as a lost with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a pivot table field, you must type a new name for the field."**

I have checked but the name

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTable()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    
    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")
    
    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    'Define Pivot Cache ---> ERROR HERE 
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="AccountPivotTable")
    
    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AccountPivotTable")
    
    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Billing Account Number")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Name Of Service Point")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2 'if want to input 2 dimensions for row fields
    End With
   
    'Insert Data Field
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccountPivotTable").PivotFields("Billing Account Number")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "#"
    .Name = "Number of Account"
    End With
    
    'Format Pivot Table
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight9"

    'Format Pivot
    PTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
    PTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight19"
    
    'Set the layout to "Show in Tabular Form"
    PTable.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    
    'Disable subtotals
    PTable.ColumnGrand = False
    PTable.RowGrand = False
    PTable.DisplayFieldCaptions = False
End Sub
```

Please help me identify the error and how to fix it

Comment: That error sounds like it's more to do with your data than the code. You should post a screenshot of your data.

Comment: You cannot assign a PivotTable to a PivotCache object. Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Comment: Please try it.

    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AccountPivotTable")